# Incorrect results with Spring data JPA findAll() method

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have entity class defined as below.Data is getting saved in all the child entity(Address,BankAccounts) table correctly. However while trying to fetch data from child table using ParentEntity findAll() function it is retrieving only the first record from child table.
Data is available in DB.
I am using Spring Data JPA
**implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.7.RELEASE'**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
data class EmployeeEntity(

    .....

    @OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    val addresses: List<Address>,

    @OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL))
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    val bankaccounts: List<BankAccounts>

)
```

Actual Result

```
[
    {
        .........
        "addresses": [
            {
                address 1
            },
            {
                address 1
            }
        ],
        "bankaccounts": [
        {
            account 1
        },
        {
            account 1
        }

        ]
    }
  ]
```

Expected Result

```
[
    {
        .........
        "addresses": [
            {
                address 1
            },
            {
                address 2
            }
        ],
        "bankaccounts": [
        {
          account 1
        },
        {
          account 2
        }

        ]
    }
  ]




  @Repository
interface EmployeeRepository : JpaRepository<EmployeeEntity, String?> {

}
```

Comment: hi & welcome! :) You cannot have "duplicate (join) column" (name), so please try (e.g.) `name = "adress_id"` and `name = "account_id"`

Comment: @xerx593 thanks for the reply :) i changed the name as suggested and kept referencedColumnName = "id" for both .Still getting only first address two times.Infact when i tried with only 1 child entity onetomany mapping i still have same issue.

Comment: This is  OnetoMany unidirectional mapping so I have only OnetoMany from Employee(Parent entity) to Address & BankAccounts (Child entities). So there is no @ManytoOne declared in child entity.

Comment: That (still) makes sense...but of course data should conform with your expectations ...how do you initialize(/clean-up) your db?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you .Do you mean how I clean up  table mapped to these entity class?